# Celery beat schedule multiple tasks under same time-interval group

Tags: python, flask, celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to set up two tasks that both run every minute. Is there any way to group them in one to run?

I specified `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` in my `celeryconfig.py` as following:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (1,2)
    },
}
```

So if I want to run two tasks, I would expect something like this?

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute': {
        'task': ['tasks.add','task.multiply'],
        'schedule': [crontab(minute='*/1'),crontab(minute='*/1')],
        'args': [(1,2),(3,4)]
    },
}
```

However it did not work. Is there any standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Celery Documentation: Periodic Tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries) states that you can only have the name of the task to be executed (not a list, etc.)

You could create two different schedule entries:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute_add': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (1,2)
    },
    'every-minute_multiply': {
        'task': 'task.multiply',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (3,4)
    },
}
```

Comment: That's what ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'every-minute': {
    'task': 'tasks.add',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    'args': (1,2)
},
```

}

You can use single task celery for your work to be done as per your question.
Your tasks.py should be

```
def multiply(p1,p2):
  return p1*p2

def add(x,y):
  z=multiply(3,4)
  return x+y,z
```